# How to change SecureConversationVersion property in SessionSecurityToken class

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to configure Security Token Service using WCF so it could create tokens (SessionSecurityToken) using WSSecureConversationFebruary2005 namespace. SessionSecurityToken class has property SecureConversationVersion which in theory can be set to my desired value. Unfortunately by default it is not and I don't see a way to change it. After analysing source code I noticed that there is constructor which can change this value but it is internal.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.sessionsecuritytoken.secureconversationversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Code I use for hosting STS looks like:

```
                BindingElementCollection bindings = new BindingElementCollection();
                SecurityBindingElement security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
                security.AllowInsecureTransport = true;
                security.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
                security.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
                bindings.Add(security);

                TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textMessageEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
                bindings.Add(textMessageEncoding);
                textMessageEncoding.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressingAugust2004;

                HttpTransportBindingElement httpsTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
                bindings.Add(httpsTransport);
                var myBinding = new CustomBinding(bindings);

                var host = new WSTrustServiceHost(Configuration, new Uri(BaseAddress));
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(
                    typeof(IWSTrustFeb2005SyncContract),
                    myBinding,
                    STS_ADDRESS);
```

The example response looks like:

```
<t:RequestedSecurityToken>
<SecurityContextToken d6p1:Id="_6d497e66-9851-4b74-bf6d-e5f46c652837-35820CA1B23B6109FC1DC2F6A0D3ACC3" 
xmlns:d6p1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512">
<Identifier>urn:uuid:b067f4fc-0adc-4e78-98a5-449c6b58c234</Identifier>
<Cookie xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/security"></Cookie>
</SecurityContextToken>
</t:RequestedSecurityToken>
```

But instead of docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512 I expect schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to achieve my goal by creating custom token handler that overrides WriteToken method. The implementation is a slightly modified version from base class and looks like this:

```
public class MyTokenHandler : SessionSecurityTokenHandler
{
    public override void WriteToken(XmlWriter writer, SecurityToken token)
    {
        SessionSecurityToken sessionSecurityToken = token as SessionSecurityToken;
        sessionSecurityToken.IsReferenceMode = true;
        string ns = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc";
        string localName = "SecurityContextToken";
        string localName2 = "Identifier";

        XmlDictionaryWriter xmlDictionaryWriter;

        if (writer is XmlDictionaryWriter)
        {
            xmlDictionaryWriter = (XmlDictionaryWriter)writer;
        }
        else
        {
            xmlDictionaryWriter = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateDictionaryWriter(writer);
        }

        xmlDictionaryWriter.WriteStartElement(localName, ns);
        xmlDictionaryWriter.WriteElementString(localName2, ns, sessionSecurityToken.ContextId.ToString());
        xmlDictionaryWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xmlDictionaryWriter.Flush();
    }
}
```

Probably this is not most elegant solution but I couldn't find better.